# Android: UI design for calendar

Tags: android

I am planning to develop a calendar UI with time displayed horizontally and date vertically. Please refer the image below:

http://i54.tinypic.com/a2uiw8.png

The following is my design requirement for the above attached UI design:

1. This UI should be allowed to scroll horizontally and vertically
2. While scrolling horizontally, first column with date to be static and not moved horizontally. Only Meeting schedule and time in the top should scroll
3. When scrolling vertically, top most rows with time and "my calendar" text shouldn't move and it should be static. Only Date column and meeting columns should scroll

My questions:

1. What is the best layout for this ?
   I guess tablelayout is the good one to use
2. How to implement the design requirements mentioned in 2 and 3 using table layout or any other layout?

I am trying to find a solution for this. But couldn't find a better one. Please help me on this.

Thanks..

Comment: Anybody have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

A tablelayout could be used, but you could also use relativelayout.

About the second question I can't give a complete answer but I might point you in the right direction.

You'll need to capture where the finger is and only move the outer column and rows when the finger movement is changed. So these will be static and only changed from code somehow. The inner parts which move all the time has to be made from a component that allows scrolling in both direction with the full content inside. But how and which views to use, I don't know. You might have to split this question up into multiple parts but please first try to find the answer by taking it 1 problem at a time :)